# On premises data gateway in PowerBI: Deployment Requirements

Tags: deployment, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals, power-bi-report-server

I have been working on a dashboard in PowerBI and the client is currently hosting their data on premises which can be accessed via a secure VPN. The database is in SQL, and they will further expose an API in the secure network to connect to PowerBI for the dashboard. This dashboard will further be embedded in a flask application and be visible to the public.

Now I further researched on on premises deployment in these use cases, and I have the following doubts:

- Will I only be needing a VM for PowerBI Data gateway installation to connect to the database and further connect it to my PowerBI dashboard and then further requiring a linux server to bundle my dashboard as an application and deploy it?
- Some instances showed me to have a requirement of a powerBI server, is it necessary or the powerBI data gateway would do?

Any article or advice regarding deployment would be really appreciated, since there is not much clarity in microsoft docs.

I have yet tried to read the docs and understand how PowerBI data gateway works, but not a clear understanding how report server and data gateway is different. In the end, I should be able to host my PowerBI dashboard and then embed it an application.